# Replace a column with another column if another is not null in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a dataframe using Pandas in which I have to replace a column if another colum value is not null.

My dataframe is something like:

```
v_4        v5             s_5     vt_5     ex_5          pfv           pfv_cat
0-50      StoreSale     Clothes   8-Apr   above 100   FatimaStore       Shoes
0-50      StoreSale     Clothes   8-Apr   0-50        DiscountWorld     Clothes
51-100    CleanShop     Clothes   4-Dec   51-100      BetterUncle       Shoes
```

So, I want to replace `v_5` with `pfv` where `pfv` is not null, how can I achieve that?

Comment: You can try that :)
`DF[numpy.isnan(DF["pfv"])]["v_5 "] =DF["pfv"] `

Comment: Do you think missing values are empty strings?

Comment: I think these are 'null'.

Comment: Not `NaN` or `None`s ?

Comment: So `df.loc[df['pfv'].ne('null'), 'v5'] = df["pfv"]` working for you?

Answer (score 21):

You should consider using the numpy [where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function which runs much faster the all the apply methods.

Where is basically if else function for vectors. The first entry is a vector with the condition, the second the value if true and third if false. Here is how it would look:

```
import numpy as np
df['v_5'] = np.where(~df['pfv'].isnull(),df['pfv'],df['v_5'])
```

Good luck

Answer (score 5):

Because missing values are strings `null`, use:

```
df.loc[df['pfv'].ne('null'), 'v5'] = df["pfv"]
print (df)
      v_4             v5      s_5   vt_5       ex_5            pfv  pfv_cat
0    0-50      StoreSale  Clothes  8-Apr  above 100           null    Shoes
1    0-50  DiscountWorld  Clothes  8-Apr       0-50  DiscountWorld  Clothes
2  51-100    BetterUncle  Clothes  4-Dec     51-100    BetterUncle    Shoes
```

If missing values are `NaN` or `None`s (not strings) use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['v5'] = df['pfv'].fillna(df['v5'])

print (df)
      v_4             v5      s_5   vt_5       ex_5            pfv  pfv_cat
0    0-50      StoreSale  Clothes  8-Apr  above 100            NaN    Shoes
1    0-50  DiscountWorld  Clothes  8-Apr       0-50  DiscountWorld  Clothes
2  51-100    BetterUncle  Clothes  4-Dec     51-100    BetterUncle    Shoes
```

Answer (score 3):

Late in the game but if truly `nulls` (not `'null'` strings), you could also use

```
df['v_5'] = df['pfv'].combine_first(df['v_5'])
```

which is equivalent to `COALESCE()` in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is the same of jezrael, but with one more step, based on an essay I made with the null problem.
I've added one more row for a pfv without values.

```
    data = [['0-50','StoreSale','Clothes','8-Apr','above 100','FatimaStore','Shoes'],
    ['0-50','StoreSale','Clothes','8-Apr','0-50','DiscountWorld','Clothes'],
    ['51-100','CleanShop','Clothes','4-Dec','51-100','BetterUncle','Shoes'],
    ['0-50','StoreSale','Clothes','12-Apr','above 100','','Clothes']]
```

First step is to handle nulls. 'df' is the DataFrame.

```
    df = df.replace('', np.nan)

          v_4         v5      s_5    vt_5       ex_5            pfv  pfv_cat
    0    0-50  StoreSale  Clothes   8-Apr  above 100    FatimaStore    Shoes
    1    0-50  StoreSale  Clothes   8-Apr       0-50  DiscountWorld  Clothes
    2  51-100  CleanShop  Clothes   4-Dec     51-100    BetterUncle    Shoes
    3    0-50  StoreSale  Clothes  12-Apr  above 100            NaN  Clothes
```

Now let's update the v5 column.
The command says that we will replace v5 for pfv, but if pfv is NaN we will replace with the current value of v5.

```
    df['v5'] = df['pfv'].fillna(df['v5'])


    print(df)

         v_4             v5      s_5    vt_5       ex_5            pfv  pfv_cat
    0    0-50    FatimaStore  Clothes   8-Apr  above 100    FatimaStore    Shoes
    1    0-50  DiscountWorld  Clothes   8-Apr       0-50  DiscountWorld  Clothes
    2  51-100    BetterUncle  Clothes   4-Dec     51-100    BetterUncle    Shoes
    3    0-50      StoreSale  Clothes  12-Apr  above 100            NaN  Clothes
```

Comment: Hmmm, how do you know information missing values are empty strings?

Comment: I don't know. I've made an essay, leaving a blank in pfv. When I tried fillna it didn't worked, because there was no NaNs to fill. I posted the answer just in case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Series.update](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.update.html) from `pandas` to replace with non-NA values from passed Series.

Therefore you need first to replace 'null' with NaN.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

 df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
               'B': ['x', 'null', 'z']})

 # Replace null with nan
 df.loc[:,'B']  =  df.loc[:,'B'].replace('null', np.nan)
 # Update column, only if other column is non-nan (inplace)
 df.A.update(df.B)
```

Or if you don't want to change null with NaN

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

 df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
               'B': ['x', 'null', 'z']})

 # Replace null with nan
 temp  =  df.loc[:,'B'].replace('null', np.nan)
 # Update column, only if other column is non-nan (inplace)
 df.A.update(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method from `pandas` and `numpy`:

```
df['v_5'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['pfv'] if row['pfv']==np.NaN else row['v_5'], axis=1)
```

or without numpy :

```
df['v_5'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['pfv'] if pd.isnull(row['pfv']) else row['v_5'], axis=1)
```